# Example of a maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ be the set of bounded continuous functions from the set of real numbers to itself. Then $A$ is a ring under pointwise addition and multiplication. The set $I$ of all functions $f \in A$ satisfying $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ is an ideal in $A$. Hence by Zorn's lemma there is a maximal proper ideal in $A$ that contains $I$. Can someone give me an "explicit example" of such an ideal?

Comment: Since the space of maximal ideals in $A$ [is the Čech-Stone compactification of $\Bbb R$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451223/the-stone-%C4%8Cech-compactification-of-a-space-by-the-maximal-ideals-of-the-ring-of), I suspect that an explicit example is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

In general the maximal ideals of rings of continuous functions do not have nice descriptions.  The ones that share a single point $x$ in their zero set are easy to describe, but the others are hard to describe.