# Stone-Cech compactification and maximal ideal of C(X)

Tags: general-topology

Please i want to know the usefulness of the "Gelfand and Kolmogoroff theorem" when showing that $\beta X$ of a a completely regular Hausdorff space $X$ Can be identified with the Structure space of $C(X)$ ring of continuous real-valued functions on $X.$

Comment: Nobody to help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/451318/4280 might help? Gelfand-Kolmogorov is called Stone's theorem there. It seems to be used on the way to the construction.