# Which of the following statements are correct regarding $I(x)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $X=(0,1)$ be the open unit interval and $C(X,\mathbb R)$ be the
> ring of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R.$For any $x\in
>  (0,1),$let $I(x)=\{f\in C(X,\mathbb R):f(x)=0\}.$Then which of the
> following is true?
>
> $(1)I(x)$ is a prime ideal.
>
> $(2)I(x)$ is a maximal ideal.
>
> $(3)$Every maximal ideal of $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is equal to $I(x)$ for
> some $x\in X.$
>
> $(4)$ $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is an integral domain.

**$I(x)$ is a Prime ideal**

let $f(x),g(x)\in C(X,\mathbb R)$.For any $x\in (0,1),$ let $f(x)g(x)\in I(x)\implies f(x)g(x)=0\implies $ either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$ $\implies$ either $f(x)\in I(x)$ or $g(x)\in I.$

$I(x)$ is a prime ideal

**$I(x)$ is Not an Integral domain**

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if 0<x $\le$ 1/2} \\
x-1/2, & \text{if 1/2$\le$ x<1}
\end{cases}$

$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x-1/2,  & \text{if 0<x $\le$ 1/2} \\
0, & \text{if 1/2$\le$ x<1}
\end{cases}$

then $f(x)\neq 0$ and $g(x)\neq 0$,but $f(x)g(x)=0$

So, $C(X,\mathbb R)$ is Not an integral domain.

Please comment on option (2) and option (3),also check whether my arguments are correct or not?

Thank you!

Comment: No hint given for (3) ?

Comment: @reuns:there is no hint given...

Comment: 1-3 are answered many times on the site already. Poke around a bit. if you don't find anything ping me and I'll find them when I have a chance.  4 is easy to produce a counterexample for.

Comment: @rschwieb: I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375400/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-real-functions-on-0-1  ,but here X =[0,1] but in my case X=(0,1)...Will this make any difference?

Comment: I think your proof for (1) is incorrect. You are saying $f(x).g(x) = 0 \implies f(x) = 0 \lor g(x) = 0$, but as in your second proof, you have shown that this ring can have zero divisors so both $f,g$ can be non-zero

Comment: @Axo:Yes,i did'nt noticed it...can you point out the mistake?

Comment: @Hilbert Yes, it makes a difference.   [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3545958/29335) is a solution relevant to you.

Comment: @Hilbert Denote function $f$ in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ as $f(X)$ to make notation unambiguous. Now if $f(X) \cdot g(X) \in I(x)$, it implies the fixed point $x \in X$ is a root of $f(X) \cdot g(X)$ or $f(x) \cdot g(x) = 0$. Now, you can claim that $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ which has no zero divisors so either $f(x) = 0 \lor g(x) = 0$, thus showing $I(x)$ is prime. In your writeup, this distinction isn't made between $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(X)$.